# Linear Algebra (transformations)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Im having trouble with this problem. I would really like som help solving it.

If $T: P_1\rightarrow P_1$ is a linear transformation such that $T(1+5 x) = 1 + 4 x$ and $T(3 + 14 x) = 3  - 3 x$, then

$T(2 - 5 x) = ?$

Comment: What is P1     $ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$-43(1+5x) + 15(3+14x) = 2-5x$$

Answer (score 0):

The thing to note is that the polynomials of order 1 are a vector space.  Using the standard basis, the above problem is equivalent to asking the following:

We know
$T\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 5\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 4\end{bmatrix}$ and
$T\begin{bmatrix}3\\ 14\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}3\\ -3\end{bmatrix}$.  So what is $T\begin{bmatrix}2\\ -5\end{bmatrix}$?

$T$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix.  From the above, we have the following equations:
\begin{align}
  T_{11} + 5 T_{12} &= 1 \\
  T_{21} + 5 T_{22} &= 4 \\
  3T_{11} + 14T_{12} &= 3 \\
  3T_{21} + 14T_{22} &= -3.
\end{align}

From here, you can figure out the elements of $T$ and multiply it with the vector $(2,-5)$.  The convert back to polynomials.